# modifying the QTY input box function in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I've managed to remove the QTY box from the Product page but I'm looking to remove all instances of it as my business model is based on only having one of each product

Is it possible to set it in a way that the user can't change the value? I understand that you can limit it in the back end but is it possible to have it fixed and not an input box?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit that via admin.

No need to go remove all qty boxes everywhere.

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options -> Limit Maximum Qty
```

Comment: Thanks I understand that it can be done that way, I'm just looking for a cleaner looking way of achieving it, from a design point of view an imputable qty box serves no purpose if there is only 1 to buy